# Two image tables or one for storing default images?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently maintain a single DB table that has some info for images that are stored in a file system.  This setup works well with the several hundred thousand photos I currently have recorded.

For a users default image I maintain a separate folder that contains the photo but this has become a maintenance nightmare. Should I create a second table that stores a reference to the default photo from table 1 or is it better to add a new field in table 1 that's a boolean I can set to indicate a default photo?

My table looks something like this:

```
image_table
id  user_id  file_name 
1   6        xvy.jpeg  
2   6        abc.jpeg  
3   6        def.jpeg
```

Proposed solution:

```
image_table
id  user_id  file_name default
1   6        xvy.jpeg  0
2   6        abc.jpeg  1
3   6        def.jpeg  0
```

In this proposed solution it seems as though I would need to make two SQL calls to reset the default and then a second call to set a new default photo if a user changes it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to add new fields instead of add new tables, if the second table would have identical columns to the first if you went that approach.

Reasoning: If I need to get values from both tables, I would need to do a cumbersome UNION. What if you had three or more tables that all had the same kind of data, and I wanted all of them at once? It just gets clunkier and clunkier and more awkward to code against.

Comment: That makes sense although it seems like the mysql query might get messy trying to reset the value and assign it to another field for the default photo...

Comment: You can do foreign-key references to the same table you're in (called a self join) - so you can have the query structure you had in mind without needing to make a new table.

Comment: I added a proposed solution that from what I understand will still require two SQL calls in order to change a default photo...

Comment: If a user can have only one default photo at a time, why not make user have a new field 'default photo' that is a foreign key on photos?

Comment: so adding a new field in another table correct? That would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can see you are using some SQL database but dont take me wrong why dont you try a NoSQL database such as MongoDB . I know creating a field as a flag or creating a new table doesnt seems to be a good design.